# Why comment is displayed in the error message in Command Prompt?

Tags: java

The comment should not be displayed in the error message. Please explain why it is so.

```
class Test { 
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    static int x= 10; //Error: Static local variables are not allowed 
} 
}
```

o/p -

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programs>javac Test.java
Test.java:3: error: illegal start of expression
        static int x= 10; //Error: Static local variables are not allowed
        ^
1 error
```

If we move it to next line, the comment is not displayed.

```
class Test { 
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    static int x= 10; 
    //Error: Static local variables are not allowed 
} 
}
```

o/p ->

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programs>javac Test.java
Test.java:3: error: illegal start of expression
        static int x= 10;
        ^
1 error
```

Comment: _The comment should not be displayed in the error message._ Why not?

Comment: You can't use static to declare a variable inside a method.

Comment: As we add comment so that it wont displayed in the console.

Comment: When Java cites a line of code as an error, it doesn't strip the comment if there is one. What makes you believe it would or should?

Comment: In your second example the comment isn't displayed because, simply, it's no longer on the same line as the error. The error message shows the entire line that has the error. There's no reason for it to show the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The java compiler just shows the whole line containg the error. Including the comment helps you to see which line it was in a lengthy source file.